# OData query option like "$select" not working when expecting xml resposnse

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Facing an issue while working on ODATA with xml response. Getting internal server error at client side. I debug the code at server side nothing went wrong here, proper response object is generating and returning from server side but "500 internal server" error is generating at client end. Same thing perfectly working fine for when we ask for json response. One more thing I wanted to add here when I hit the url without "$select" proper xml response is generating. Please find below the code for both client and server side.

```js
function ConnectXML()
{
 var url = 'https://localhost:321/api/performance?$select=EmployeeID';
 $.ajax({     
   type     : "GET",
   url      : url,
   dataType: "xml",
   success  : function(msg){ alert('Success'); } ,
   error    : function(msg) { alert('Failed'); } 
}); 
}
```

```
public IQueryable<AppraisalsList> GetAppraisals()
    {
        try
        {
            string appraisalType = string.Empty;

            var allUrlKeyValues = ControllerContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

            string type = allUrlKeyValues.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "type").Value;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) && type.ToLower() != "regular" && type.ToLower() != "ondemand")
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid query params"));

            BusinessLogic.Appraisal.Appraisal appraisal = new BusinessLogic.Appraisal.Appraisal(new Settings() { Language = "en-US", UserID = 1, ConnectiongString = "Server=Kazim;Database=BEPMS_BEDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultiSubnetFailover=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;", AdminConnectiongString = "Server=Kazim;Database=BEPMS_AdminPortal;Integrated Security=SSPI; MultiSubnetFailover=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;", ApplicationResourcePath = @"D:\Projects\BullseyeEvaluation Performance Management System\BullseyePerformance\Main Project\Source\Binaries", FiscalYearStart = 1, FiscalMonths = 12, DateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy", NumberFormat = "123,456.78", DecimalPlaces = 2 });
            return appraisal.GetAppraisalsList(type).AsQueryable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Some error occured while processing your request"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to specify the "accept" header in your ajax request:
 $.ajax({headers: { Accept : "application/xml" }, ... });

Comment: I tried your solution but fruitless. Also i believe this has no link by passing header. If that is the case it should also throw error when we used it without "$select"

Comment: Yes, you are right. Anyway, check that the Accept header is "application/atom+xml" (I just read that what OData supports is AtomPub). 
Check also that you have the [EnableQuery] attribute with AllowedQueryOptions.Select in your action method.
And if that is the case, it may be something related with the collection where you try to apply the $Select query. OData does that when returning the entity, this is why you can not catch the exception in the action method. Try to catch it before the response is sent, to see if you can see more information, with a DelegatingHandler, for example.